# Deploy sql+winforms application on Linux/Ubuntu while development server is still Windows

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, mono

I have a very limited knowledge for Linux/Ubuntu platform.
There are some requirements coming though for me to deploy a version of our desktop application on either of the above platforms.

With the context, I have the following queries in my mind:

1. Could the same code can run on windows using the MONO/MONO IDE and I can compile the output to the OS specific?
2. OR assuming there are certain changes I must make to run them on different OS, what could be the best way to deploy it on Linux/Ubuntu?
3. OR Is it possible to keep the same code under windows development, however can be deployed on Linux/Unix environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL wont work on Unix so you'll need to convert that first.

1. Yes thats the way to go.
2. You need to do step 1 to work out if there are required changes specific to OS's.
3. Assuming that everything required by the assembly is supported by Mono, you shouldn't have to do anything - it should already be binary compatible. That's one of the points of IL :)

If you do find some things that aren't supported by Mono, suggest you have a Unix branch of code.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I appriciate the answer.